# Kafka Synchronous Producer Latency after Java17 and spring version upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have upgraded my service
from :
Java 8
spring-boot version: 1.5.4
spring Kafka version: 1.1.6
Kafka client version 0.10.1

to
Java 17
spring-boot version: 2.6.6
spring Kafka version: 2.8.4
kafka client version: 3.0.1

I wanted to check if the upgrade is causing any performance degradation
On running a performance test at a total of 1500 TPS on both the old and new versions I have observed that the synchronous producer shows a 150ms + latency compared to the old version.
What can be the possible reason behind this

Comment: Probably the matter of metadata for the topic fetched by the producer synchronously. See if your caching is appropriate: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#producerconfigs_metadata.max.age.ms. It is really hard to compare that old version with new Apache Kafka architecture.